# How can I tell Apache2, run mod_php5 by default but run this VH in CGI mode?

Tags: php, linux, apache, cgi, mod-php

**The Server**

I have a development server that I'm using to host my current projects. Here are some stats:

```
root@myserver:/usr/bin $ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=maverick
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.10"
root@myserver:/usr/bin $ apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Nov 18 2010 21:17:43
root@myserver:/usr/bin $ php --version
PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.1 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Oct 15 2010 14:00:18)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
root@myserver:/usr/bin $ uname -r
2.6.35-22-server
```

**The Problem**

I'm running PHP 5.3.3 using `mod_php5` and it's working great. But I need to run PHP 5.2.11 for just one VH on the server, so I used [phpfarm](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/Introducing%20phpfarm.htm) to compile PHP 5.2.11. I want to configure Apache to use mod_php5 for everything on the server except for this VH. I'll run PHP 5.2.11 for this one VH over FastCGI.

**My Test**

As a test, I'm using Apache's default site at `/var/www`. I set up the following directory files to report PHP versions to me:

- /var/www/phpinfo.php
- /var/www/php-5.2.11/phpinfo.php

My objective is to have `/var/www/phpinfo.php` show me version 5.3.3 (mod_php5) and have `/var/www/php-5.2.11/phpinfo.php` show me 5.2.11 (CGI). This isn't working yet.

I inserted the following code `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`:

```
FastCgiServer /var/www/cgi-bin/php-cgi-5.2.11
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin-php/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
```

I inserted the following code into the default site's VH definition:

```
<Directory /var/www/php-5.2.11/>
    AddHandler php-cgi .php
    Action php-cgi /cgi-bin-php/php-cgi-5.2.11
</Directory>
```

**Results**

With `mod_php5` enabled:

- /var/www/phpinfo.php ---> 5.3.3 (`mod_php5`)
- /var/www/php-5.2.11/phpinfo.php ---> 5.3.3 (`mod_php5`)

With `mod_php5` disabled:

- /var/www/phpinfo.php ---> no handler; Firefox tries to download the PHP file
- /var/www/php-5.2.11/phpinfo.php ---> 5.2.11 (CGI)

**The Files Involved**

http://files.mattalexander.me/apacheconfig.tgz

Comment: Does it have to be mod_php, or is it sufficient if you can run X different versions of PHP?

Comment: I'd like it to be `mod_php` if at all possible. Were you going to suggest that I just set a default CGI handler and shutoff `mod_php` for good?

Comment: More or less. There's `su_php` which is 1) flexible, as you can install a gazillion handlers and 2) is more secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good alternative is [suPHP](http://suphp.org/Home.html).

If set up properly, you can have as many handlers, as you wish; even for different directories within a virtual host.

For added security, there's suPHP's "paranoid" mode in which you assign a Unix user and group to a virtual host and the scripts will be run as that user.

My suPHP config looks like that:

```
...

[handlers]
;Handler for php-scripts
x-httpd-php=php:/usr/bin/php4-cgi
x-httpd-php5=php:/usr/bin/php5-cgi

;Handler for CGI-scripts
x-suphp-cgi=execute:!self

...
```

Within a simple `.htaccess` file it is possible to have scripts run using different versions of PHP:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
   SetHandler x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch \.php5$>
   SetHandler x-httpd-php5
</FilesMatch>

# etc...
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `mod_php` still handles `.php` files, even when the CGI handler is set for a vhost.

To fix that, the `<Directory>` in the vhost needs to have a `SetHandler` directive:

```
  Action php-cgi /cgi-bin-php/php-cgi-5.2.11
  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler php-cgi
  </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

I've updated the [tutorial](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/Running%20Apache%20with%20a%20dozen%20PHP%20versions.htm).